# wordpress if/else php conditional logic --- ignore if logged in, only work on these two pages

Tags: php, wordpress

Can anybody point me in the right direction here. I have tried googling but can't find my exact use case.

I am having an issue editing a page using beaver builder when I am running chatra & proof on the site. so i am trying to use conditionals so that if a user is logged in do nothing and if you arent logged in and you are page x and y run the two app scripts.

The conditional i have now hides the scripts from admin (woohoo!) and displays them on pages ----but not only on the two pages listed.
here is the code i'm using :

https://gist.github.com/llamedia/30387f0913202f771b8299e3837e53d3

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!` operator negates logical result of `is_user_logged_in()` method.

`&&` operator has meaning of logical AND.

So, If you want to add something to page when user is **not** logged in **and** is browsing page with ID 9 or 14, you should write this:

```
<?php if (!is_user_logged_in() && (is_page(9) || is_page(14))): ?>
    <!-- user is not logged in and is browsing page 9 or 14 --> 
    <script src="..."></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

To read more about PHP operators I suggest reading [official PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php).

Comment: i will give this a shot. my brain doesn't work in conditional logic. when someone shows me the better way to do it, i always say --- so simple, makes so much sense --- but my brain doesn't think that way!

Thanks so much!